# Wordpress custom meta query very slow AND relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

My webpage was very slow and I have found out that the reason is this query, which takes between 10 and 20 seconds at least.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'version',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_wpcf_belongs_car_id',
            'value' => $car_id,
        ),
        'power-clause' => array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-power',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'numeric',
        ),
        'gear-clause' => array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-gear',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'numeric',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
    'power-clause' => 'ASC',
    'gear-clause' => 'ASC',
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,);
```

get_posts($args);

Do you see something that can be optimized? Any ideas about the approach I should take? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: how many posts are being returned at once?

Comment: hundreds? because this should't take 20 seconds.

Comment: Not really, a car normally has between 2 and 5 versions... that's why I don't understand why this takes so long.